# Software to capture screen and create tutorial about using some software

Tags: windows, screen-recording

My team is developing some software and we need to make some tutorials about it.

Which software can I use to capture screen actions (keyboard and mouse events, software responses)?

If possible, allowing inclusion of voice narration, text balloons, action buttons (like "click here to go to next step").

We are using both Windows 7 and 8.

Comment: Related: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/239/what-is-a-screen-recorder-with-mouse-movement-and-can-save-the-recording-as-vide

Comment: This question isn't very clear.

Comment: Second @w3d, the requirements are very similar ("screen capture" with "input device tracking" plus "voice over" and "text overlays"). Marking them as duplicates is probably best for future visitors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html)** fits some of your needs. It’s specially focused on screencasts, and provides features that you are looking for, such as:

- It **captures the mouse cursor**, and you can even configure your video so that it indicates when clicks happen, either with sounds or with visual effects.
- It allows the inclusion of **voice narration**. It provides several tracks for that, which I find often helpful unless you record everything in a row.
- It lets you add **text balloons** and many other visual effects and different kinds of annotations that are useful in screencasts.
- It's quite **user-friendly**.

@EnergyNumbers linked in the comments [the official list of features](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia-pc-mac-comparison.html), and according to this user:

> [Camtasia] does now capture **keyboard input**. And you can add **interaction** too.

I guess the only disadvantage is that this application **is not free**, but it has a free 30 trial.

Comment: If you're looking for just images, [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) by the same company (TechSmith) is second to none.

Comment: [Camtasia Features are listed here](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia-pc-mac-comparison.html) - it does now capture keyboard input. And you can add interaction too. Great tool.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [EzVid](http://www.ezvid.com/)?

Ezvid is a screen recorder program that comes with an in-built video editor where you can split your recordings and add text in between two clips, creating a slideshow effect. You can even upload the video to YouTube through the program itself.

For gamers, there’s an option to enable ‘Gaming mode’ where it records the windowed mode of your game. The program comes with a few music clips. However if you decide to have no music, it will be replaced with a ‘Silent machine’ which sounds like a small fan from a computer. You can add in other pictures and video clips, as well as add in your voice after you’re done editing your clip.