# Cell phone emulation to capture screen action?

Tags: android, screen-recording, emulator

I need to create a tutorial about using a Samsung S2 / S3 / S4 application.

Is there any simulator that I can run on my computer, so that I can use some screen capture software to create the tutorial ?

Comment: How is this different from http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/335/software-to-capture-screen-and-create-tutorial-about-using-some-software?

Comment: In that question I need a software to capture screen. In this question I need a software to run a cell phone app that will be captured afterwards.

Comment: The standard android emulator should work, but it's slow as heck. I would get a HDMI capture device and plug in a android phone into that.

Comment: @Austin [It isn't even clear whether hardware recommendations are off-topic](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/112/are-hardware-recommendations-on-topic). If the answer to a software question involves some hardware, go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BlueStacks](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http://bluestacks.com/&ei=Fv_yUveIIuGIygGV0oCADQ&usg=AFQjCNEUwBhsISBYDsenjhMifbGO9qCluA&sig2=zsRBAQRtqpfD5TfYo-0Vig&bvm=bv.60799247,d.b2I)

Is a beta android emulator. Has some slowness/crashing  but it should work with a bit of work and is currently free. (it does have options to emulate specific phones but I haven't checked their accuracy in comparison to any real phones).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Android-x86 + VirtualBox](http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/)

- free and open-source
- Windows/Mac/Linux

> Want to run Android on your PC? The Android-x86 Project has ported
>   Android to the x86 platform from ARM. Android-x86 can be installed on
>   netbooks with supported hardware, but you can also install Android in
>   VirtualBox.
>
> Android can be run as just another virtual machine, like you would run
>   a Windows or Linux virtual machine. This allows you to play with the
>   Android interface and install apps in a full Android environment on
>   your PC.
>
> Before you can get started, you’ll need both VirtualBox and an
>   Android-x86 ISO to install inside VirtualBox.
>
> Install VirtualBox:
>
> - Download and install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) if you don’t
>     already have it installed.
> - Download an [Android-x86 ISO](https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list): You can find
>     the latest Android-x86 ISO files at Google Code. Download the latest
>     one — currently Android 4.2.

[image]