# Screen capture software that can record 3D games

Tags: windows, screen-recording

I am wondering if there is a screen-to-video tool out there that can take good, professional-looking videos of 3D games. It doesn't necessarily have to be free. It must support Windows 8.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4165/10687 has a list of free ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For video games, you can use [Fraps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraps):

- Straightforward to use
- light
- non-free
- you can change the FPS and the resolution
- Windows 8 ([game capture only](https://encodingtalk.com/threads/record-windows-8-desktop.2038/))

[image]

Answer (score 9):

There are quite some the best ones are probably:

- [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/)
- [xSplit](https://www.xsplit.com/)
- [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/)

Fraps:

- Costs Money
- displays FPS and has many other cool features
- Trial version
- Can make High Quality Screenshots
- Can only record Games

xSplit:

- Costs Money
- Mainly made for LiveStreams but also good to just record Games
- Can record Desktop

OBS:

- Free, Open Source
- Mainly made for Livestreaming, but records just as well
- Can Record Desktop

Answer (score 1):

I've streamed for a long time now and I've always used

- XSplit if I need a specific UI (ads, banners, text, webcam). It's pretty good quality and not that resource heavy. You'd use that for livestreaming, or very long videos (playing diablo in HC and wanting to have the moment of your death on video)
- Fraps : Basically captures everything that is in the current window. Uncompressed, videos are really heavy, and the software itself is also resource heavy. But the uncompressed video is really good and you can do any editing you want afterwards. This is what you'd use if, for example, you'd want to record Raids in wow. Record, then edit, then publish.
- (NVIDIA USERS ONLY) Shadowplay : This is amazingly good and very, very VERY light. Only works for nvidia users since it's a built-in software that does pretty much the same as Fraps but without the lag. If you have an Nvidia card, use that instead of fraps.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand [D3DGear](http://www.d3dgear.com), a very fast game recording software for 3D games.

> [It] allows users to record game play to movie without slowing down the game. D3DGear software has very minimal performance impact on the game and may not cause a game to lag or drop frame rate.
>
> D3DGear software recording produces high quality video with small file size, and it supports microphone recording, Push-To-Talk recording and face camera overlay[...]

- It comes with a 15 day trial. The full version costs $34.95
- It supports Windows 7 and 8

Comment: Thanks, Timmy – I was just about to complain about missing details ;)

Comment: @Izzy I'd hate to see a valid solution get deleted for being in a low quality answer, and the information was there on the website

Answer (score 0):

I like [Loilo](http://loilo.tv/us/product/game_recorder). Features that you might like include:

- Free
- No watermark unless you use the trial editing software. (In my case I plan to use Windows movie maker when the trial is over)
- You can record as long as you want I record pretty long videos.
- For me I found it seemed to use less resources then Fraps and Bandicam when recording. May depend on settings of all software)

I tried a few others and this was the only one that seemed to work well. The only caveat is that it comes bundled with a trial for video editing software.

Answer (score 0):

Dxtory

The steam gaming client has a built-in streaming option.

The AMD video drivers has a built-in utility.

NVIDIA has shadowplay