# Screen capture software for Windows XP?

Tags: screen-recording, windows-xp

Exactly this question: [A free, lightweight but quality video capture software for Windows?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4165/a-free-lightweight-but-quality-video-capture-software-for-windows)

***But for windows xp.***

I tried Rylstim which did run but caused applications to run slower than normal. Which is an additional requirement, as I need this software in order to compare performance of my application before and after a patch, the capture software cannot impede the performance at all.

Rylstim also had a feature that showed mouse clicks (although it didn't work very well) which was a very useful feature that I would like in other software also.

The FPS and output format is inconsequential, the only requirement is that it cannot affect performance of other running applications (on a low end single core computer). Showing mouseclicks is nice but not required.

I've also tried Snagit and Obs, both sounded and looked good to me but both didn't work because of Windows XP incompatibility.

Comment: **Do not close as a duplicate** This question is specifically for XP, the one pointed to is specifically for Win 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For video games, you can use [Fraps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraps):

- Straightforward to use
- light
- non-free
- you can change the FPS and the resolution
- Windows XP, 2003, Vista, and Windows 7 (on Windows 8 it's [game capture only](https://encodingtalk.com/threads/record-windows-8-desktop.2038/))

[image]

Comment: it would be good if you edited your other answer in the linked question to include the other OS's that fraps works on for a more complete answer that will help future people like myself find an answer to a similar question

Answer (score 1):

I am now on Win 7, but used CamStudio under Win XP for many years.  It is also available as a portable app from [PortableApps](http://portableapps.com)  Portable Apps is moving away from XP support, so I don't know if their currently available version will work satisfactorily on XP.  CamStudio has settable FPS, can capture or ignore audio, and be configured with pre-sets, and is generally quite flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TechSmith Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html) 8.3.0 :

- Windows XP Service Pack 3 ([Camtasia Studio 8.3.0 was the last version that officially worked with Windows XP](https://feedback.techsmith.com/techsmith/topics/camtasia-running-on-windows-xp); [20 May, 2014: Camtasia Studio v8.4.0: Removed support for the Windows XP operating system](https://www.techsmith.com/camtasia-version-history.html))
- non-free
- plenty of freatures

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HyperCam](http://www.solveigmm.com/en/products/hypercam/):

- v3 is non-free, but v2 is free (with watermark)
- Windows XP and later
- straightforward to use
- light
- FPS can be changed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/):

- free and open source
- Windows XP/Vista/7/8/8.1, OS 10.4+
- Record directly to .GIF or .LCF.

[image]