# Screen recording to gif showing which keys are pressed for Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows-7, screen-recording

I'm looking for a program running on Microsoft Windows 7 that allows users to:

1. screen record to gif;
2. shows which keys are pressed during the recording; (<-- this is the future missing on the gif screen recorders I have tried so far such as
   [ShareX](https://github.com/ShareX) or [LICEcap](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/24774/903))
3. select which area of the screen to record.

Any license or price is fine.

Answer (score 1):

[Captura](https://github.com/MathewSachin/Captura) (gratis, MIT license, has a portable version) allows users to screen record to gif showing which keys are pressed for Microsoft Windows. Examples:

[image]

[image]

The location of the shown keys on the recording is very much configurable:

[image]

[image]

Note: As of Nov 8, 2022, Captura is no longer maintained.