# Screen recording showing which keys are pressed for Android

Tags: android, screen-recording, keyboard

I'm looking for a screen recording  program showing which keys are pressed for Android. Any license or price is fine.

---

[Example](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/78442/903) of screen recording on Microsoft windows 7 showing which keys are pressed:

[image]

Comment: Hi Franck. Not long ago, I came across an application that did exactly this.  I thought it looked good, but I didn't need it, so I didn't bookmark it.  Sorry.  If I stumble across it again, I'll definitely let you know.  I might have been browsing though F-Droid or Android SE at the time, so you might want to take a quick look there too. I checked my browser history, and it was a bit too long ago for it to be there, but I'll look through a couple backups for you when I have a little time and see if it's there.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket thanks yes please keep me posted if you stumble across it again!

Comment: I will for sure.  BTW, it's a long-shot, but also it's possible that Accessibility features on some Android ROMs may have a feature to show the keystrokes... then you can use *adb* (or likely an screen recording app) to record.

Comment: Well, Franck, I performed a bunch of searching, and I didn't find what you want.  I did find this great related Firefox extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/addon_screen_key/  I recognize it's not exactly what you want, but I thought perhaps in combination with a screen recording utility it could help you.  I tested this on desktop Firefox, and it worked well, but I ran out of spare time before I could test to see if it works on mobile Firefox too.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket thanks, great to know about the extension!

Comment: You're welcome.  I'll also continue to keep my eyes out for anything that may more exactly fit your needs.