# Program for video recording for Windows

Tags: video, windows-10, screen-recording

I want to record my screen for video guides. I want to only record a Windows window. Which are programs free for Windows? And I want to edit my videos in a free editor. It might be a different software.

Comment: possible duplicate: [A free, lightweight but quality video capture software for Windows?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4165/3579)

Comment: It is had different answers.

Comment: it must have different answers and a lot more answers due to its age

Comment: I want to use a modern program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open-source Captura has the feature you're looking for.

https://mathewsachin.github.io/Captura/