# Software to make video from a game

Tags: windows, windows-7

I would like to record videos from some games I am playing. I tried Fraps, but it had problems sometimes with recording audio. To be more precise, it was missing sometimes. I need software which would record such video without any limitations in time. What I definitely don´t want to have are some annoying watermarks. It doesn't matter if software is free, it just needs to meet the requirements mentioned above.

Comment: Why are everyone answering the duplicate, ffs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A free, lightweight but quality video capture software for Windows?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4165/a-free-lightweight-but-quality-video-capture-software-for-windows)

Comment: @Nakilon I need it for Windows 7, not 8.1.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend:

- OBS Studio: https://obsproject.com/

Other candidates:

- VLC, how to do it: https://www.wikihow.com/Screen-Capture-to-File-Using-VLC
- ScreenToGif https://www.screentogif.com/ -it is also possible to install some plugins for video formats.

Comment: Certainly the "industry" standard

Answer (score 1):

One can use [TechSmith Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html):

- Windows 7 (and >7)
- non-free
- plenty of features
- high-quality recording

I've used it to record video games.

Comment: "non-free" But there seems to bee a free version as well, or what that Free download mean?

Comment: @convert just a trial

Answer (score 1):

Here some posibilities:

[Вandicam Screen Recorder](https://www.bandicam.com/free-screen-recorder/)

[Mirillis Action](https://store.steampowered.com/app/228180/Action__Gameplay_Recording_and_Streaming/)

[PlayClaw 6](https://store.steampowered.com/app/746390/PlayClaw__Overlays_Game_Recording__Streaming/)

[Nvidia ShadowPlay](https://www.nvidia.com/en-in/geforce/geforce-experience/shadowplay/)

[ReLive](https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/software-gaming-media)

Comment: Note that Nvidia Shadowplay works through Geforce Experience and a supported dedicated Nvidia GPU, which is basically any GTX or RTX GPU since the 600 series (but not the mobile GT versions).

Comment: If I like 2 out of your 5 suggestions, should I upvote 0.4 or downvote 0.6? Please don't suggest multiple tools in one answer. Also, please provide details on how each tool solves the problem and meets the requirements.

Comment: Bandicam does not list Windows 7 as a valid OS.

Comment: Nvidia Shadowplay does not list Windows 7 as a valid OS. 10 and 11 only

Comment: @Thomas Weller It saies for Вandicam Screen Recorder "Windows 10, 11 compatible", but that doesn´t automatically mean that Windows 7 is not suported. I read somewhere it even still suports XP.

Comment: @Thomas Weller I checked myself that Вandicam is runing on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

[VSDC Video Editor](https://www.videosoftdev.com/free-video-editor/download) has Screen Recorder function to record video. I have to admit that it's not the best solution, but the other 2 solutions that I would prefer to this one count as spam here.

Comment: "it's not the best solution" - Why is it not the "best" solution? Does it meet the requirements mentioned above? "the other 2 solutions that I would prefer to this one count as spam here" - What do you mean? What "other 2 solutions"?

Comment: @MrWhite You can read here https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3010/82369