# "Quick & easy" video uploader?

Tags: web-apps, video, sharing, hosted

Is there some service where I can just upload a video to the web quickly, just to, for example, show somebody a screen recording I just made or something?

Kind of like imgur, but for videos.

I know you can use YouTube for unlisted videos, but that's kind of crude and a bit bloated for such a simple thing. I don't want anything like Gyazo, I want a way to post any video quickly (not just screen recordings), and I especially don't want it to be a GIF.

Comment: A quick Google search shows up [vdd.me](https://vidd.me/): *"Upload and host your videos instantly. No signup needed - just drag and drop."*. Never used it though.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. My choice

I quickly upload my videos use:

[**ShareX**](https://getsharex.com/) — open source program with many features and settings,
[**Streamable**](https://streamable.com/) — free video hosting with [**unlimited uploads**](https://about.streamable.com/get-started) for any video formats.

---

### 2. Limits

1. ShareX only for Windows.
2. Streamable limits for one video: [**10Gb size and 10 minutes duration**](http://help.streamable.com/article/17-faq). 10 minutes is may have very little time, but if you as I record screen video, usually you should be enough for 10 minutes.
3. Streamable have slightly video editing capabilities. For example, we can not disable video repeat. Therefore, we must edit our videos use third-party programs: usually [**ActivePresenter**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1884/23324) — my program for video recording — enough for me.

If you are satisfied with the limits, read how to set up and use ShareX+Streamable.

---

### 3. Setting

Register on Streamable → install and run ShareX → <kbd>Right_Click</kbd> to ShareX tray icon → `Destinations`

[image: Destinations]

→ `Destination settings...` → Select `Streamable` in left bar → enter your Streamable login and password.

[image: Streamable]

Again <kbd>Right_Click</kbd> to ShareX tray icon → `Destinations` → `File Uploader...` → select `Streamable`:

[image: Select Streamable]

---

### 4. Usage

After any actions in this section you will have uploaded file on Streamable and link to uploaded file in your clipboard.

#### 1. Context menu of video files

In Windows Explorer <kbd>Right_Click</kbd> to video file → select and click to `Upload with ShareX`:

[image: Upload with ShareX]

#### 2. ShareX menu

<kbd>Right_Click</kbd> to ShareX tray icon → `Upload` → `Upload file...` → select your file in Windows Explorer → `Open`. This method is preferred for me: I save my screen record videos in one folder and I can quickly select it.

#### 3. Drag'n'Drop

<kbd>Right_Click</kbd> to ShareX tray icon → `Upload` → `Drag and drop upload...` . Now drag and drop your video file to bottom right corner.

[image: Drag'n'Drop]