# Screen recorder that can hide sensitive information on the fly, in real time

Tags: screen-recording, privacy

I want to record some demos on my PC (Windows or Linux), but some of the software or webpages I will be showing contains sensitive information. I believe this is doable with video editing, but when I do a live demo, this not an option.

I could also use a software that would hide some predefined spots on the screen, by doing something like placing small black windows always on top. But I don't know if such a software exists.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding screen recorders, you can check the answers on [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/239/6834)

Concerning the privacy part, here's an [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org) script that uses black gui windows with the "always on top" feature to hide anything below them. Use the hotkey <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to create a black box at the location of the mouse cursor. Modify the first two lines of the script to change the block dimensions. Note that you can *only* insert up to 99 of these blocks before having to reload the script.

Just install AutoHotKey, save the following code in a `.ahk`, and run it

```
blockWidth = 200
blockHeight = 50

;; End of configuration section

#NoEnv
#Persistent
#SingleInstance

SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

guiIndex := 1
while true
  {
  #b::
    MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
    Gui %guiIndex%:Default
    Gui, +AlwaysOnTop -Caption
    Gui, %guiIndex%:Color, 000000
    Gui, %guiIndex%:Show, x%xpos% y%ypos% w%blockWidth% h%blockHeight%
    guiIndex := guiIndex + 1
  return
}
```

Here is an example:

[image]