# Edit video file while retaining the original format

Tags: windows, video, audio, video-editing, gui

I need a piece of Windows software that can edit (split, trim, concatenate, etc) both common (MP4) and relatively-uncommon (MKV) video formats **while retaining the original format** (resolution, bitrate, codec, etc), ideally with options to convert too.

One example is that I have ripped my brilliant *[Monk](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0312172/?ref_=nv_sr_3)* boxset using the equally-brilliant [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) and I wish to extract 13:26 - 14:06 of S02E15 (don't ask) whilst retaining the following format:

[image]

> **Video**
>   Frame width: 720
>   Frame height: 572
>   Data rate: 1690kbps
>   Total bitrate: 1850kbps
>   Frame rate: 25 frames/second
>
> **Audio**
>   Bit rate: 159kbps
>   Channels: 2 (stereo)
>   Audio sample rate: 48 kHz

Another example is that my GoPro Hero, configured to use the 1080p 30fps video mode, can seemingly only record 17 minutes and 35 seconds before it hits a 2GB limit and creates another file. I would like to concatenate these into one video but also, if possible, compress the data.

I have tried many, many, MANY pieces of software (both free and commercial) to try to do these things but there's always one crucial thing that they do wrong such as:

- Not support a certain format, most commonly MKVs
- Only let you export to preset profiles (Xbox One, PSP, iPhone, iPad, etc)
- Are overly complicated and require intricate knowledge of media editing
- Add watermarks
- Screw up the video / audio quality, sync, etc
- Screw up the black areas (I don't know the right term) by actually making them part of the video

etc

If there is a magical piece of software that can do all or most of this, I don't care if it's paid or free.

Thanks.

**Edit (17/02/2015 22:19)**: I'm aware that FFmpeg is an incredibly powerful command-line utility but it's preferable that this software has a GUI.

Comment: Can you list the software you've already tried so that answers don't repeat it?

Comment: Maybe [MP4 Direct Cut](http://www.fame-ring.com/sk/mp4-direct-cut.html) aka. [Smart Cutter](http://www.fame-ring.com/smart_cutter.html)

Comment: Handbrake, maybe? I think it has a decent number of the features from that bullet list iirc. Profiles definitely.

Comment: I ended up using [Shotcut](https://www.shotcut.org/). I'm pretty sure that it's not lossless but I can't tell the difference and the ease-of-use and open sourceness makes up for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been very happy with [Shotcut](https://www.shotcut.org/).

Answer (score 2):

[VideoReDo TV Suite](http://www.videoredo.com/en/Products_TVSuite_V5.html) should do what you want, it's useful for trimming/splitting video files (you can also remove ads in your videos).

> With VideoReDo's perfected smart
>   rendering technology you can edit
>   again and again without degrading
>   any of your precious videos.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use many of DVDVideoSoft's [programs](https://www.dvdvideosoft.com/free-dvd-video-software-download.htm) to manipulate media files.
You could try their [Free Video Editor](https://www.dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-Video-Dub.htm)
Unfortunately (and perhaps, ironically) it's not free if you want to keep the original format, but converting to other formats is.
It should meet your requirements except it can't concatenate videos;

It's very easy to use and can edit *.avi, *.mpg, *.mp4, *.mkv, *.flv, *.3gp, *.webm, *.wmv.
You may have a hard time finding software that can concatenate while keeping the original format, if the videos are different. Unfourtunately I don't have any recommendations there.

**NOTE:** DVDVideoSoft's products are freeware. DVDVideoSoft may bundle links to other websites and third-party apps installations including toolbars in its products. Make sure to opt-out if you don't want any of those (I don't recommend them myself, but I also bought premium)