# Free video cutter and joiner tool for windows

Tags: gratis, video-editing

For the last few days I was checking for a good software that cut and join different videos. Which software is a good one ?

It should be a free one. It can up to 100 MB in size. It should be fast and should have a good user interface. The primary job of the software should be video cutting and joining. If it has others features too, its not a problem.

Comment: There are a few good recommendations for free video editors on [this question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/175/83).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft Movie Maker](http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Segments-of-a-Video-File-with-Microsoft-Movie-Maker-2012):

- free
- [cut and join](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/work-with-clips-in-windows-movie-maker) different videos.

[image]

[image]