# Video editing software like Sony Vegas

Tags: windows, gratis, video-editing

I am looking for a free program - similar to Sony Vegas - that will allow me to creat professional-looking videos.
**This program would ideally have the following features:**

- Ability to import existing video files and edit them
- Ability to add music
- Professional looking fonts and effects
- User-friendly UI; preferably not a big learning curve
- Doesn't need administrator privileges to install, as I'm not the administrator.
- Windows 7 is the operating system I use

Comment: See http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2009/83

Comment: I've been looking for something like this for years.. Never found it.

Comment: See also [Easy-to-learn video editor for Windows?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16725/easy-to-learn-video-editor-for-windows)

Answer (score 3):

[Lightworks](http://www.lwks.com/) offers a free version.

- I found it was more capable then Windows Movie Maker
- Has a free version that is limited compared to the pro version.
- Ability to import existing video files and edit them
- Ability to add music (I recorded talking with Audacity and was able to add that so adding music should be possible.
- I use windows 7.

I did have to watch some of the tutorial videos in order for me to figure a few things out.  I apologize if it doesn't meet your other requirements I'm not sure on some of them.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your two recommendations so we can compare the UI? Preferably while performing one of the tasks at hand.

Comment: Will try later there are a bunch of Demos on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0A9TUrS99mU)

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Movie maker might be an option](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/16119/10687) User tehDorf added answer to other thread.

- May already be installed on your computer
- I'm pretty sure adding music is possible
- I think the UI is simpler then Lightworks

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org/) which is a mature (v3.1.1 currently) and open-source video editor.

- cross platform and Win 7 64bit is still supported
- imports videos
- add as many audio tracks as needed
- quite user-friendly and clean UI in my opinion
- no admin privileges needed
- has some really nice and professional looking fonts/texts known as *Title*, which can be furthered edited via [Inkscape](https://www.inkscape.org)