# Basic video editing and DVD creation software for Windows?

Tags: windows, video, video-editing, optical-media

I'm looking for some software to let me to cut/splice some home video, then make a DVD I can play in a DVD player. An additional feature that would be nice is if I could edit the audio levels of the clips before recombining them so that they are all the same volume.

**Edit (apologies for the lack of detail):**

I am looking for a Windows application. XP would be preferred, but I have an 8.1 as well. I am expecting there is a free option available for the limited functionality I need.

I have a 1 GB HD video that is 1.25 hours long. Here is the relevant information from VLC:
Stream 0

- Type: Video
- Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
- Resolution: 1280x720
- Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV
  Stream 1
- Type: Audio
- Codec: MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a)

**Needed Features:**

- The video is a school play, so there are a number of 1-2 minute pauses that I would like to edit/cut out.
- After I remove the pauses, I would like to put the whole thing on a DVD. Ideally I would like it to work like a VHS: just put the disk in and it starts playing the entire video.

**Some extra features that would be nice:**

- It would be nice if I could adjust the audio levels so that each part is about the same volume (some parts are quiet, some are louder)
- For the DVD playback, I would like to be able to set up a menu where the user can select the particular part they want to watch. It would also be nice if the DVD would start playing by itself after a minute or two if the user doesn't do anything.

Comment: A little more details needed e.g.: free or bought, which OS, etc.

Comment: As Steve pointed out: without at least OS and budget mentioned, this question cannot be answered (and might be closed for being "too broad"). You should also include whether you want a feature-rich solution, or prefer a rather easy/minimalistic software.

Comment: I'm putting this on hold because we'll need much more information to provide a solid recommendation. Please add some more details to your question - in particular, what OS must it run on? What budget do you have? What format is the home video in? Thanks!

Comment: @Undo I've updated the question, please let me know if there is anything else I can do to help get my question answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the information I needed on Scott Hanselman's blog post [How to create a DVD on Windows 8...](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCreateADVDOnWindows8EvenThoughWindowsDVDMakerIsGoneDVDStyler.aspx):

**Basic Video Editor:**
[Windows Movie Maker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-movie-maker-download) - Free, Windows
I was able to use Windows Movie Maker to do the basic editing of the video including cutting out the blank sections and adding a simple clip of white text with a black background. It's installed by default on Windows 7. It is not for Windows 8 and later, but you can get it as a [free download from Microsoft's Website.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-movie-maker-download)

**Basic DVD Creator**
[DVDStyler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/) - Free, Windows/Mac/Linux
I was able to create a simple menu with just a Title and a "Play" button, but that would also start auto-playing after 30 seconds. I did this by setting the Video Object - Pause setting to `30` and the Menu - Post Command to `jump title 1;` in the Menu's Properties.

There are some helpful resources on their website - http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/documents

Answer (score 0):

I see you are going to cut the videos first then burn the videos to DVD. 
For video cutting, there are many online video cutters that can be helpful: http://www.videoconverterfactory.com/tips/free-online-video-cutter.html With them, you do not need to install any program on your computer.

As for DVD burning, you can use DVDFlick, a free DVD authoring tool for Windows: http://www.dvdflick.net/guide/index_en.html

It can set up a menu, titles, add audio tracks, subtitles, etc. The whole burning process is quite simple, you can have a check there.

Comment: Thanks for the additional links - DVD Flick looks like it might be a little simpler than DVDStyler.