# Easy-to-learn video editor for Windows?

Tags: windows, gratis, video-editing

Last year, I was asked to help put together a short film for a non-profit, which I did with [OpenShot](http://openshot.org/) in Linux.

This year, I was asked to do it again, and even though I tried to say no, I got manipulated into accepting the job again. (*I blame my brother*)
However, this year, I don't have a Linux machine available; only Windows. (*Although if I really need it, I'll run [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/) in a VirtualBox so I can get OpenShot*)

Is there a Windows program that more or less does what OpenShot does? Since I'm doing this pro-bono (and, hopefully, only once), I'd really prefer that this software be free, as in no cost.

Requirements, in short:

- Free
- video editing software that
- doesn't require extensive training to use that's also
- compatible with Windows (8).

Comment: See also [Video editing software like Sony Vegas](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/video-editing-software-like-sony-vegas)

Comment: OpenShot is (now) compatible with and can be run on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[Lightworks](http://www.lwks.com/) offers a free version.

- I found it was more capable then Windows Movie Maker
- Has a free version that is limited compared to the pro version.

I did have to watch some of the tutorial videos in order for me to figure a few things out.

Comment: Cool hope it helps if not its the best i have found for free

Answer (score 0):

As you already know it, try the live cd in that windows machine: http://www.openshot.org/download/

Windows movie maker should be an option: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/movie-maker 
Given it is free, easy to learn, and runs on W8.

Answer (score 0):

After searching, we found **open source** software from **Microsoft Developer Network**. The **MMP** (Microsoft Media Platform) Video Editor simplifies the *editing and publishing process, enabling real-time, browser-based video editing, manage dynamic metadata and deliver exciting content to the Web.*
For more information visit this **link**

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MMP-Video-Editor-472a92fe

Answer (score 0):

Shotcut is open source and it appears pretty powerful while not being too difficult to learn.

The simplest would be [AviDemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net) - if you just want to cut and join and mux clips.