# Looking for an easy to use strong video editor, preferably free

Tags: gratis, video, video-editing

I'm wondering if anyone could recommend me a video editing program that is moderately easy to use and preferably free that can do the following:

- Set other videos in frames in the video
- Move images around at will
- Pile sound effects on top of each other
- Cut and place video clips with ease and precision
- Strong audio control, perhaps good ducking
- The ability to export to very high quality
- Compress files
- Export in 720p with a strong framerate

Anything that can do most or all of these things cheaply or free.  It can be for any operating system, as I have multiple, although Windows or Mac would be preferred.

Comment: See http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2009/83

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/features.html) is a good tool for your purpose. Also it's free

- Light weight, small in size
- Straightforward user interface
- Enough professional
- Super fast processing/converting
- ...

Answer (score 1):

I Would suggest the following softwares for your needs.

- [Lightworks](http://www.lwks.com/)The most advanced free video Non-Linear editing software that is       available and it is used for editing and mastering digital video in various formats, 
  including 2K and 4K resolutions, and television in PAL, NTSC, and high-definition formats.
- [VSDC Free Video Editor](http://download.cnet.com/VSDC-Free-Video-Editor/3000-13631_4-75764187.html) Its a free video editing tool featuring a complete set of instruments for all-round creating of videos.it features a complete set of instruments for all-round editing and creating of videos. The tool comfortably deals with dozens of video codecs and formats, while visual effects and filters help you making the final video look as pro-like as you need. Fully customizable video editing and the native support for multiple media devices contribute to flexibility of the program.also supports for dozens of video codecs and formats including but not limiting to AVI, MP4, MKV, MPG, WMV, 3GP, FLV for video; MP3, WAV, WMA, FLAC, PCM, OGG, AAC, M4A, AMR for audio; and BMP, JPG, PNG, PSD, ICO, TIFF for images, VSDC Free Video Editor provides one of the easiest ways to combine multiple source chunks in different formats into a resulting high-quality video.

Comment: This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer. Answers should at least point out how the suggested software matches the requirements, and why especially this should be chosen. Personal experience (if any) is also wished for.

Comment: @Izzy I made my answer more descriptive

Comment: That's better already; but how do the products match the requirements? Can they e.g. "Set other videos in frames in the video", "Pile sound effects on top of each other", or have "Strong audio control"? Any personal experiences with the two?

Answer (score 0):

If cost does not matter I would suggest Adobe After Effects.

But if it does I would suggest either Blender (which is not a video editor but contains a really powerful video editor) or Avidemux which is also freeware but not as powerful as blender's built in video editor